# Backbone where method for item object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

below is the sample JSON Data

```
"items": [{
                "id": "18",
                "attributes": [{
                    "identifier": "Style",
                    "value": "peacock"
                }, {
                    "identifier": "Size",
                    "value": "L"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "300438",
                "attributes": [{
                    "identifier": "Style",
                    "value": "peacock"
                }, {
                    "identifier": "Size",
                    "value": "M"
                }]
            }]
```

I need to get the item id where Style = peacock and Size = L.
How can I do this using backbone?

I have made a collection like

```
var itemsCollection = new IEA.Collection(itemsData)
```

This has all the items.

Answer (score 0):

underscore.js does not support filtering of nested objects ,you can use a combination between filter and where functions

```
filteredItems = itemsCollection.filter(function(item) {
  return _.where(item.get("attributes"), {
      "identifier": "Style",
      "value": "peacock"
    }).length > 0 &&
    _.where(item.get("attributes"), {
      "identifier": "Size",
      "value": "M"
    }).length > 0;
});
```

Comment: if you have only one item you are looking for is better to use find instead of filter

Answer (score 0):

Alternate.I simplified the JSON by creating new array and the storing desired values in that.
Then i Used backbone where method for returning the id.

```
 productData.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    var data = {'id': item.id};

                    item.attributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
                        data[attribute.identifier] = attribute.value
                    });

                    productVariants.push(data);
                });
```

var itemsCollection = new backbone.Collection(productVariants);